# Different condition between 4 variables

Tags: php, conditional-statements

Discount array

```
 $Discount=arrray(
 0=>array('FromArea'=>0,'ToArea'=>0,'Master'=>0,'Slave'=>0),
 1=>array('FromArea'=>0,'ToArea'=>10,'Master'=>5,'Slave'=>0),
 2=>array('FromArea'=>5,'ToArea'=>0,'Master'=>0,'Slave'=>8),
 3=>array('FromArea'=>0,'ToArea'=>0,'Master'=>1,'Slave'=>2),
 4=>array('FromArea'=>0,'ToArea'=>1,'Master'=>7,'Slave'=>5),
 ...
 )
```

I want get discount amount base on input parameter of function.

If !empty(parameter) then check it in array

Like this

```
function DiscountAmount($FromArea, $ToArea, $Master, $Slave){
    foreach ($Discounts as $R) {
         if (!empty($FromArea) && empty($ToArea) && empty($Master) && empty($Slave)) {
              if ($R["FromArea"] == $FromArea)
                  return true;
         } else if (!empty($FromArea) && !empty($ToArea) && empty($Master) && empty($Slave)) {
              if ($R["FromArea"] == $FromArea && $R["ToArea"] == $ToArea)
                  return true;
         } else if (!empty($FromArea) && !empty($ToArea) && !empty($Master) && empty($Slave)) {
              if ($R["FromArea"] == $FromArea && $R["ToArea"] == $ToArea && $R["Master"] == $Master)
                  return true;
         } else if (!empty($FromArea) && !empty($ToArea) && !empty($Master) && !empty($Slave)) {
              if ($R["FromArea"] == $FromArea && $R["ToArea"] == $ToArea && $R["Master"] == $Master && $R["Slave"] == $Slave)
                  return true;
         } else if (!empty($FromArea) && !empty($ToArea) && !empty($Master) && !empty($Slave)) {
              if ($R["FromArea"] == $FromArea && $R["ToArea"] == $ToArea && $R["Master"] == $Master && $R["Slave"] == $Slave)
                  return true;
         }
         ...
      }
}
$amout=DiscountAmount(0, 0, 0, 0);
$amout=DiscountAmount(1, 0, 0, 0);
$amout=DiscountAmount(0, 1, 0, 0);
$amout=DiscountAmount(0, 0, 1, 0);
$amout=DiscountAmount(0, 0, 0, 1);
$amout=DiscountAmount(1, 1, 0, 0);
$amout=DiscountAmount(1, 0, 1, 0);
$amout=DiscountAmount(1, 0, 0, 1;
$amout=DiscountAmount(1, 1, 1, 0);
$amout=DiscountAmount(1, 1, 0, 1);
$amout=DiscountAmount(1, 1, 1, 0);
$amout=DiscountAmount(1, 1, 1, 1);
....
```

[Online Demo](http://ideone.com/n48QHq)
But with this way you must check very case. Is there a simpler solution to do it?

Comment: Perhaps, instead of using 4 independent parameters for the function, you can build it with a single parameter (which would be an array with length 4) and then iterating over the parameter. I'll try to post my code idea as an answer (It's been a long time since the last time I used PHP)

Comment: if you can set pseudo code that do it

Comment: It took me lots of time because I am out and online through my mobile phone, but I did post the answer

Comment: I reanalyzed the problem and improved my answer. Please check it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34109654/different-condition-between-4-variables/34109960#34109960

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function DiscountAmount($FromArea, $ToArea, $Master, $Slave)
{
  //This line's simply to save time:  if all fields are empty, no need to check further
  if(empty($FromArea) && empty($ToArea) && empty($Master) && empty($Slave)) 
       return true;    
  foreach ($Discounts as $R)
  if (equiv($FromArea, $R["FromArea"]) &&
      equiv($ToArea,   $R["ToArea"  ]) &&
      equiv($Master,   $R["Master"  ]) &&
      equiv($Slave,    $R["Slave"   ]))
        return true;

  return false;
}

function equiv($Field,$OtherField)
{
  if (empty($Field)) return true;
  else return $Field == $OtherField;
}
```

This ought to be significantly less clunky.

Comment: You're not providing us with a lot of information.  You didn't say how it didn't work.  I don't know what your output is intended to be, and I can't run your code as is.  Why not tell us?

Comment: check your code on ideone.com/l38zVQ  your code not correct answer in all time

Comment: I see you've copied the code over to that site.  You didn't say how it didn't work, or in what circumstance.  I don't know what your output is intended to be.  WHy not tell us?

Comment: I'm glad you've found your solution.  Please click the check mark by that answer and give ChiliNut credit.

Comment: The @Will Briggs code only needs to check if all variables are empty at the beginning, but the code is correct.

Comment: Now your code is correct and simplify and beauty ,thank your for help

Answer (score 2):

```
function DiscountAmount($FromArea = null, $ToArea = null, $Master = null, $Slave = null) {
    global $Discounts; //pull discount array into the function
    $argsCount = count(func_get_args()); //the number of arguments filled in
    $checkArray = array(
        'FromArea' => $FromArea, 'ToArea' => $ToArea, 'Master' => $Master, 'Slave' => $Slave
    );
    while (count($checkArray) < $argsCount) {
        array_pop($checkArray);
    }
    foreach ($Discounts as $R) {
        if ($checkArray == $R) { //checks if all key/value pairs are equal
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with a regular expression:

```
function DiscountAmount($FromArea = null, $ToArea = null, $Master = null, $Slave = null){

    if(empty($FromArea) && empty($ToArea) && empty($Master) && empty($Slave)) return true;

    global $Discounts;

    $json = json_encode($Discounts);

    $reg = "/\{";

    if(!empty($FromArea))   $reg .= "(?:[^\}]*\"FromArea\":{$FromArea})";
    if(!empty($ToArea))     $reg .= "(?:[^\}]*\"ToArea\":{$ToArea})";
    if(!empty($Master))     $reg .= "(?:[^\}]*\"Master\":{$Master})";
    if(!empty($Slave))      $reg .= "(?:[^\}]*\"Slave\":{$Slave})";

    $reg .= "[^\}]*\}/";

    return preg_match($reg, $json);     

}
```

Comment: I've tested it in my environment and the result is 1

Comment: The variable in my code is $Discount and you declare $Discounts at the beginning with "s". Please check again with the correct var names, my code runs very well.

Comment: If all parameters are empty you want to return "true"?

Comment: Then you don't need to do the check at the beginning in @Will Briggs code. The result will be "1", that is "true".

Comment: Neither in my code, if you do not do the check the result will be 1 if all variables are empty. I'm glad that you solved your problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think this will eliminate the redundancy:

```
function DiscountAmount($Parameters){
    foreach ($Discounts as $R) {
        foreach ($Parameters as $PK => $P) {
            $CheckFlag = true;
            if (!empty($P)) {
                if ($R[$PK] != $P) {
                    $CheckFlag = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!empty($CheckFlag)) { return true; }
    }
    return false;
}
```

#### Assumptions:

Based on the question's code and the accepted answer:

> - If any of the arrays has non-empty values that match the input values, the function must return true
> - If all input arrays are empty, function must return true

#### Test

http://ideone.com/otiUJw

Comment: No with this way can not set && on input

Comment: I think you won't need it. Please do rubberduck debugging with the code and you'll see. If I'm not wrong, the loop I made will check any combination of (a, b, c, d) checking only non-empty parameters

Comment: Unless you mean to insert boolean expressions as a parameter... in which case maybe I did overlook something, and my sample would not be valid for this case